# How to remove empty rows using SSIS tools from a flat file source?

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to remove all empty rows from my flat file in SSIS. I tried using Conditional Split to resolve this problem, but that solution is not the best option for the task I'm working on. I was wondering is there any C# code that will delete all empty rows that I can use in Script Component? I'm new with SSIS and c#, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you just trying to remove the rows in the flat file and then save the file again?  or remove them prior to importing into a SQL table/DB?  If importing option probably easier to import into temp table, then delete the empty rows.

Comment: An alternative approach is to apply a staging environment consisting of one or more database staging tables in a database that are truncated and repopulated with each run of the SSIS package.  It is very useful for traceability and also for performing functions, like you've requested, more easily.  Modularize your approach with several steps by 1) importing all of your rows from the flat file to a staging table, 2) clean up the staging table with SQL, and 3) import the cleaned up records (excluding nulls) to the final database destination.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some C# to help you out. You aren't very clear about what a null row means:

This will work a script component and will let you work with the non empty row:

```
using System.IO; //This gets you to File (Way up top with the rest of the usings)

public static void Main()
{
    string path = @"c:\[where ever you file is located].txt";

    // Check path.
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

       foreach(string line in lines)
       {
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) //Not null or empty
         {
              //[DO STUFF -- use split if you want to go to data flow]
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your flat file source is Excel, try the approach outlined in the following link.

https://devjef.wordpress.com/2014/02/05/ssis-remove-empty-rows-from-excel-import/

You mentioned that the conditional split is not the best approach, but did not state why.  Perhaps the above will help verify that you're applying it correctly, since you are new to SSIS.

Hope this helps.